# How to manage POM surefire plugin for two different test suite in same project

Tags: java, junit

I am using Maven with the surefire plugin to run my tests. I have several different tests and for run to all I am using same POM. Currently all are working fine but now I have two different properties file's for get some entry for my test cases so I want to run all these  test cases for these two different properties one by one. I mean I want to use two different test suite for it, So How can I manage the POM for regarding??
any help will be appreciated..!!!

Using - JDK 1.6 and Maven 3.1

Answer (score 1):

If you can start two maven build one after another then try something like that:

```
                         <execution>
                            <id>integration-test</id>
                            <phase>integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <excludes>
                                       <exclude>**/test/**${dontUse}.properties</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/test/**${use}.properties</include>
                                </includes>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
```

and pass the dontUse and use as a parameter to maven. Or you can define two profiles - one with including the first, one with the other properties-file - and then startthe build with these two profiles. 
Edit: Load the property-file with one single class where you check if the file exists. Either the first or the second.
Something like that:

```
public Properties load() {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    try {
        InputStream in;
        in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("first.properties");
        if (in == null)
            in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("second.properties");
        prop.load(in);
        in.close();
        return prop;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return prop;
}
```

Comment: Failsafe is better than Surefire for use in the integration test phases

Comment: Thanks Jan for replying, It work's. But how can I do same only with one time maven build. Is it possible with Surefire?

Comment: I'm not sure, writing this from home so I can't test it. But maybe it's possible to define two identical execution with distiguishing  configuration and execuition-ids but with the same phase. Worth to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the standard:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>suite1.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    <suiteXmlFile>suite2.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```